# PHP Foreach inside with create a new Objects

Tags: php, oop, silverstripe

I'm a little confused about how I can amend the following code that generates a form to allow for the `$Show->DateTimes()` to automatically generate a set of new fields and populate the price  depending on how many dates are available.

I'm not sure if this is even possible. Although I have added the foreach inside the comments explaining how I think it should work, I think I just have my PHP mixed up.

I have this code at the moment:

EDIT: Final fixed code:

```
public function RegistrationForm() {
    $date_id = (int) $this->getRequest()->requestVar('DateID');

    if(!$date = DataObject::get_by_id("ShowDateTime", $date_id)) {
        return $this->httpError(404);
    }

    $date_map = array();
    if($Show = $date->Show()) {
        if($all_dates = $Show->DateTimes()) {
            $date_map = $all_dates->toDropdownMap('Price','DateLabel');
        }   
    }

    $fields = new Fieldset (
        new TextField('Event', _t('Show.Event','Name of Event'),$Show->Title),
        new EmailField('Name', _t('Show.Name','Name')),
        new EmailField('Email', _t('Show.Email','Email')),
        new TextField('Address', _t('Show.Address','Address')),
        new TextField('Telephone', _t('Show.Telephone','Telephone')),
        new DropdownField('DateID', _t('Show.CHOOSEDATE','Choose a show'), $date_map, $date_id)         
    );

    // Loop through the time/events creating a fieldset for: class,horse,number,price
    $i =0;
    foreach($all_dates as $show_price){
        $fields->push(new TextField('Class_'.$i, 'Class'));
        $fields->push(new TextField('Horse_'.$i, 'Horse'));
        $fields->push(new TextField('Number_'.$i, 'Number'));
        $fields->push(new CurrencyField('Price_'.$i, 'Price',$show_price->Price));
        $i++;
    }


    $form = new Form (
        $this,
        "RegistrationForm",
        $fields,        
        new FieldSet (
            new FormAction('doRegister', _t('Show.REGISTER','Register'))
        ),
        new RequiredFields('Event','Name','DateID')
    );

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `$form = new Form (` you can not place a loop expression. You can only put simple expressions in there, like a `$variable` or `new`. But nothing that needs a higher level of execution.

So first generate a list of the objects into variables of it's own (or one array) and then add it to `$form`.

The Form constructor expects to get a FieldSet object containing the fields. You can create a new one and add the fields to it and then pass this object into the constructor. Consider the following, alternative approach:

```
   $controller = $this;
   $name = 'RegistrationForm';
   $fields = new FieldSet();
   // add fields to $fields, setup $actions ...
   $form = new Form($controller, $name, $fields, $actions);
```

Comment: I tried this first although create a new Fieldset() only works from inside the new Form()

Comment: Ok thanks I see I only need one Fieldset although I still cant figure out how to append a loop of fields to the new Fieldset()

Comment: Try with `$fields->push(new XXXField(...));` - docs are here: http://api.silverstripe.org/2.4/forms/fields-structural/FieldSet.html